# css code for a custom font

Tags: css, custom-font

Hello I have a CSS containing

```
@font-face {
    font-family: pixelated;
src: url('jd_lcd_rounded.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight:40;
}

/*classes*/
.sign {
font-family: pixelated;
font-size: 24px;
font-weight: strong;
color:#FF8C00;
background-color:#111111;
border:5px solid;
border-color:black;
}
```

The font file was extracted from a download from 
    http://www.jeckodevelopment.com/en/fonts/jd-lcd-rounded
and when extracted, opened and "installed" shows up fine in Microsoft office...

CSS and web page code work when using default fonts...
using XAMPP in Win7

Any advice on what I'm still missing?

Comment: Which browser? TTFs don't work in IE (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp).
I believe *.woff is more portable.

Comment: I have tried a couple of other fonts from  http://www.jeckodevelopment.com/en/fonts - same non-result

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a whole set to make them work across browsers, for example:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SourceSansPro';
    src: url('/assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.eot');
    src: url('/assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/assets/fonts/SourceSansPro-Bold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

There are many online font converter services that can build you the other formats.

Comment: Thanks Diodeus - I'll make sure I remember this list! But I'm only interested in Chrome and Firefox for what I'm working on, and so the 'jd_lcd_rounded.ttf' file should be seen and the font rendered? All I get is a default font (since my test CSS doesn't name any other font).  and when I say "CSS and web page code work when using default fonts" I mean when specify a common font this font is used...

Comment: Well I found some font files work, and some don't. My code's OK so thanks all for your answers. I ended up using TIMES_SQ from http://www.fonts2u.com/